# How to keep delay after each element in a array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

While processing the array , I need to keep a delay or pause for 1.5 seconds after each element.

I tried using `$.delay(1500);`

and also tried initially using `setInterval`, but it threw an error as `setInterVal` is not defined.

Could please let me know how to resolve this error.

```
function doPoll(){

    $.each( symbols, function( index, value ){
      setInterVal(function() {
          poll(value);
      }, 1500);
    });
   setTimeout(doPoll,3000);
}

// This is my complete code 

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var symbols = [ "AAA","BBB"];

            $(document).ready(function () {

              doPoll();

            }
            );

            function doPoll(){
               $.each( symbols, function( index, value ){
                  poll(value);
            $.delay(1500);
               });
              setTimeout(doPoll,4000);
            }

            function poll(value)
            {
                alert('poll'+value);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Updated question with pollundefined error (variable i is undefined .)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var symbols = [ "AAA","BBB"];

            $(document).ready(function () {

              doPoll();

            }
            );


var i = 0;

function doPoll() {
   poll(symbols[i]);
   i++;
   if (i < symbols.length)
       setTimeout(doPoll, 3000);
}

setTimeout(doPoll, 3000);


            function poll(value)
            {
                alert('poll'+value);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `$.delay(1500)` supposed to do in your mind?

Comment: And aside from your `V` typo, you're starting a new interval at every iteration of the loop. Clearly that's wrong. If you need a delay, you don't want a loop like `.each()`.

Answer (score 1):

It is [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) not `setInterVal`. For JavaScript case matters. This is exactly what the error message says, the `setInterVal` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a delay between items, ***don't use any sort of loop like `for` or `.each()`***.

Instead maintain a counter and use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` appropriately. The way you're using them, is mixed and incorrect.

---

Here's an example using `setTimeout`:

```
var i = 0;

function doPoll() {
   poll(symbols[i]);
   i++;
   if (i < symbols.length)
       setTimeout(doPoll, 3000);
}

setTimeout(doPoll, 3000);
```

---

And here's one using `setInterval`:

```
var i = 0;

function doPoll() {
   poll(symbols[i]);
   i++;
   if (i === symbols.length)
       clearInterval(itvl);
}

var itvl = setInterval(doPoll, 3000);
```

Comment: Thank you very much i realized when i ran the example its not keeping any delay . I tried with the one you mentioned , after the first iteration its giving me pollundefined error .

Comment: Its saying the value i is undefined .

Comment: @PreethiJain: `i` isn't undefined but the `alert()` shows `undefined` because you're initially invoking `doPoll()` twice when the page loads. Once in the `.ready()` handler, and once via the initial `setTimeout`. Remove one of those and it works. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4eY83/)

Answer (score 0):

the capital V in `setInterval` makes JS look for a completely different (non existant) function. lowercase that and your interval should work.